# I am trying to build an image viewer using Tkinter but I am stuck at this weird problem

Tags: python, tkinter, pypy

I have this forward arrow button, which when clicked should display the next image in the `picturesList`. The initial image works fine, but the moment I click the forward button I get this.

```
Before Clicking
```

[image]

```
After Clicking:
```

[image]

I am adding the entire code, because I can't really understand where the problem actually is, apologies for it.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

def moveForward():
    global currImageIndex
    global imgLabel
    currImageIndex += 1

    imgLabel.grid_forget()
    print(picturesList)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(picturesList[currImageIndex]))
    imgLabel = Label(root,image=img)
    imgLabel.grid(row=0,column=1)

picturesList = []
for pictures in os.listdir('images'):
    if pictures.startswith('img'):
        picturesList.append('images/'+pictures)

currImageIndex = 0

root = Tk()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/img5.jpg"))
imgLabel = Label(image=img)
imgLabel.grid(row=0,column=1)

backwardImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/backward.ico"))
backButton = Button(image=backwardImg,width=80,height=80,relief=FLAT)
backButton.grid(row=0,column=0)


forwardImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/forward.ico"))
forwardButton = Button(image=forwardImg, width=80, height=80, relief=FLAT, command=moveForward)
forwardButton.grid(row=0,column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a reference to the image

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

def moveForward():
    global current_img
    global currImageIndex
    global imgLabel
    currImageIndex += 1

    imgLabel.grid_forget()
    print(picturesList)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(picturesList[currImageIndex]))
    current_img = img
    imgLabel = Label(root,image=img)
    imgLabel.grid(row=0,column=1)

picturesList = []

#Here is the variable where the reference will be stored
current_img = None
for pictures in os.listdir('images'):
    if pictures.startswith('img'):
        picturesList.append('images/'+pictures)

currImageIndex = 0

root = Tk()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/img5.jpg"))
imgLabel = Label(image=img)
imgLabel.grid(row=0,column=1)

backwardImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/backward.ico"))
backButton = Button(image=backwardImg,width=80,height=80,relief=FLAT)
backButton.grid(row=0,column=0)


forwardImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/forward.ico"))
forwardButton = Button(image=forwardImg, width=80, height=80, relief=FLAT, command=moveForward)
forwardButton.grid(row=0,column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This resolves my problem, but I would like to know what was the problem and how is this solution working. I mean we are just putting that image into a global variable, we are not even using that current_img inside imgLabel. Btw, thanks for helping!

Comment: I found out that it's unnecessary to use an extra variable for this i.e. current_img, just making the variable img global will do.

Comment: It can work but using globals isn't a good practice generally.